# Why When I Type "POST" Method for Wcf Service It Gives "Endpoint not found" Error?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-config, wcf-endpoint

If I use `Method = "POST"`, wcf service gives "Endpoint not found" error(.../SpellCheckerWcf.svc) .However , GET method works. I searched "Endpoint not found" subject in stackoverflow but none of them did not help. If you know the solution , please help me.

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISpellCheckerWcf
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "DoWork?params[document]={document}", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Stream DoWork(string document);
}
```

Class:

```
public class SpellCheckerWcf :ISpellCheckerWcf
{
   public Stream DoWork(string document)
   {
       JsonFormat json = new JsonFormat();
       json.document = document;
   return WriteJson(json);
   }
   private Stream WriteJson(object value)
   {
       var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       var json =
           Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(value));
       var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(json);
       WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       return memoryStream;
   }
```

Web Config:

[image]

Service Markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
Service="SpellCheckerWeb.SpellCheckerWcf" 
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `UriTemplate` needs to have query string info in it any more:

```
UriTemplate = "DoWork?params[document]={document}"
```

Try using just:

```
UriTemplate = "DoWork"
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the 'WebGet' decoration

```
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="DoWork?params[document]={document}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)>
```

Comment: thank you. As I wrote, i tried GET method and It did not gives any error, I know it. It should be POST.